# The best size of batched INSERTs in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have huge table (500 000 000 rows) of two big integers. Both columns are indexed separately. I am doing INSERTs into this table in batch using syntax:

```
INSERT into table (col1, col2) VALUES(x0, y0), (x1, y1),...;
```

When inserting small number of items (lets say 500) it gives me same time per one item as when inserting larger number of items (lets say 20000). Is this expected behavior? I thought that PostgreSQL would perform some kind of optimization when inserting more values at once. Just note: autocommit is disabled.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: In my opinion, for a large of data, try to use `COPY` instead of `Insert`.

Comment: It is not about building the table but about updating (continuous inserts)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not surprising.

If you run every insert in a single transaction, the performance will be bottlenecked by the `fsync` that forces data out to the Write Ahead Log at every commit.

But once your batches are big enough, this will be dwarved by the actual I/O, and performance should stay the same no matter how big your batches are. No matter if you insert 100 or 10000 rows, each insert does the same thing and takes the same time.

The way PostgreSQL's architecture is, the only thing that may keep you from inserting everything in a single transaction is the amount of work lost in case the transaction fails.

Comment: Does this apply at any scale period? E.g. inserting 1M rows is more efficient than batching them into 10k (assuming I don't care about the transaction potentially failing due to network issues or errors)